# One Drive - Sync issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, onedrive, synchronization

I found out that i have some sync issue with SharePoint online, sometimes when i check in my file explorer is see my status with blank. What should i do in this case ?

Normally i try to sync again, but i end up with duplicate files with computer name next to it. Which i do not want.

Another way - reset onedrive and sync again, then i do not see any folders from my sharepoint. But i see files are updating from onedrive panel.

Another Error is i see "red x" mark next to folder in file explorer. It is quit time consuming. What is solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve syncing issues in OneDrive, please perform the troubleshooting steps found on this link on Fix **[OneDrive sync problems](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-onedrive-sync-problems-0899b115-05f7-45ec-95b2-e4cc8c4670b2?redirectsourcepath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252ffix-onedrive-sync-problems-83ab0d8a-8400-45b0-8dcf-dc8aa8a6bcf8)**.